# Implementing Simple Test Driven Development

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to test the calculator program using the python unittest on the following test scenarios. But when I try to instantiate the "CalculatorClass" using the **init** it gives the following error message in the bottom. **I want to use **init** for instantiating.** I am using Visual Studio Code. Could anyone help me with this?

This is the code of "Calculator_test.py"

```
import unittest

import Calculator_steps as CalculatorClass

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.calculator = CalculatorClass.Calculator()  # instantiate the CalculatorClass
    
    def test_DecimalValues(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('3.55,8.76')
            
    def test_NonNumeric(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('7,8,e')    
            
    def test_MoreThanThreeIntegers(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('5,7,2,8')   
            
    def test_MoreThan100(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('109,76,90')
```

Following is the code of Calculator_steps.py

```
class Calculator:

    def addNumbers(self, numberlist):
        total = 0 
        if numberlist=="":
            numberlist ="0"
        numbers = numberlist.split(",")
        if len(numbers)>3:
            raise TypeError("Only three values can be entered")
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            if int(numbers[i])>100:
                raise TypeError("Only values less than 100 is allowed")
            try:
                total = total +int(numbers[i])
            except ValueError:
                TypeError("Only integers can be entered")

        return total
```

Following is the error message

```
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\mudit> py -m unittest Calculator_tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\main.py", line 100, in __init__   
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 191, in loadTestsFromName
    return self.loadTestsFromModule(obj)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 124, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 93, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
  File "C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
TypeError: TestCalculator.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The constructor of `TestCase` takes a `methodName: str` as argument. So if you want to subclass, you should match the constructor and do a super-call.

Answer (score 2):

When inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`, you do cannot overwrite the `__init__` method. Instead, anything you want to do before each test runs can be put in the `setUp` method, like so:

```
import unittest

import Calculator_steps as CalculatorClass

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    

    def setUp(self):
        self.calculator = CalculatorClass.Calculator()  # instantiate the CalculatorClass
    
    def test_DecimalValues(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('3.55,8.76')
            
    def test_NonNumeric(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('7,8,e')    
            
    def test_MoreThanThreeIntegers(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('5,7,2,8')   
            
    def test_MoreThan100(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('109,76,90')
```

To expand, the `unitttest` module is designed in such a way that special things happen in the `__init__` method of `unittest.TestCase`, and the module does not support overwriting the `__init__` method. In theory, you could overwrite the `__init__` method if you call `super().__init__` at some point during the overwritten method, but why would you want to? The unittest module is designed so that you should never need to overwrite the `__init__` method. You can use the `setUp` and `setUpClass` methods to do any instantiating needed before running your tests

Comment: @JMB Yes that's true, but again, why do you want to do this? The unittest module is not designed to have the `__init__` method overwritten. Let's put it this way: `unittest.TestCase` already has an `__init__` method that the developers of the module have written. You do not need to write your own.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer @C_Z_  This is a question in my training materials in the real world might not want to overwrite the __init__ as you mentioned. For my information how we can do this using __init__ super class call

Comment: Are you sure the training manual wants you to use `__init__` in the `TestCalculator` class? It would make more sense to use it in the `Calculator` class

Comment: I understand your point @C_Z_ as you can understand this has no practical implementation. It is only for testing the knowledge of various concepts in Python and testing the calculator code using the Testcalculator class.